# Implementing optimal strategy for "digit wars"

Tags: c++

In the "Digital Wars game" (description below), I need to develop a strategy for the computer so that the chance of winning is maximized.

The game description is as follows:
20 random digits from 0 to 9 are displayed. The user and the computer go in turns. The player can make one of two possible actions in the game:

- change one of the numbers down, maximum to 0 (there are no negative values ​​in the game);
- erase any zero and all digits to the right of it, thus reducing the length of the strip.
  The one who destroys the last zero loses.

For example:

```
  start  5 3 7 8 9 1 2 0 8 9 4 2 1 5 0 3 6 7 9 8.
  1 turn 5 3 7 8 9 1 2 0 8 9 4 2 1 5.
  2 turn 5 3 7 8 9 0 2 0 8 9 4 2 1 5.
  3 turn 5 3 7 8 9.
  4 turn 5 2 7 8 9.
  5 turn 5 1 7 8 9.
  6 turn 5 0 7 8 9.
  7 turn 5 0 7 8 8.
etc.
```

I found out that if there are two even or two odd digits and it is the computer's turn, it wins. However, I cannot come up with the algorithm for this. I need help with this part of the program, given the following implementation of "digit wars":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int coinFlip()
{
return rand() % 2;
}

void getInitialArray(int* array, int length)
{
srand(time(0));
do
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
array[index] = rand() % 10;
while (array[0] == 0);
}

void writeArray(int* array, int length)
{
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
if (array[index] >= 0)
cout << array[index];
cout << '\n';
}

int getUserDigit(int* array, int length)
{
cout << "Choose a digit``: ";

while (true)
{
int digit;
cin >> digit;
if (cin.fail())
{
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "You entered incorect value.Try again. ";
}
else if (digit > length || digit <= 0)
cout << "You entered incorect value.Try again. ";
else
return digit;
}
}

void userTurn(int* array, int &length)
{
if (length > 0)
{
int digit = getUserDigit(array, length);

if (array[0] == 0 && length == 1)
{
cout << "You lost!\n";
length = 0;
return;
}


if (array[digit - 1] == 0)
{
for (int index = digit - 1; index < length; index++)
length = digit - 1;

}
else
array[digit - 1]--;

writeArray(array, length);
}
}

void computerTurn(int* array, int& length)
{
if (length > 0)
{
cout << "Computer turn: \n";

if (array[0] == 0 && length == 1)
{
cout << "You won\n";
length = 0;
return;
}

if (length == 1) array[0]--;
else if (array[0] == 0 && array[1] == 0) length = 1;

else if (array[2] > 1) array[2]--;
else if (array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] % 2 == 1 && array[2] == 0) length = 2;
else if (array[0] % 2 == 1 && array[1] % 2 == 0 && array[2] == 0) length = 2;
else if (length > 3 && array[0] % 2 == 1 && array[1] % 2 == 1 && array[2] == 0)
{
int random = rand() % (length - 3) + 3;
if (array[random] == 0) length = random;
else array[random]--;
}
else if (length > 3 && array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] % 2 == 0 && array[2] == 0)
{
int random = rand() % (length - 3) + 3;
if (array[random] == 0) length = random;
else array[random]--;
}
else if (length == 2 && array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] % 2 == 0) array[1]--;
else if (length == 2 && array[0] % 2 == 1 && array[1] % 2 == 1) array[1]--;

else if (length == 2 && array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] % 2 == 1)
{
int random = rand() % length;
if (array[random] == 0) length = random;
else array[random]--;
}
else if (length == 2 && array[0] % 2 == 1 && array[1] % 2 == 0)
{
int random = rand() % length;
if (array[random] == 0) length = random;
else array[random]--;
}
else if (length > 2 && array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] == 0) array[0]--;
else
{
int random = rand() % (length-2)+2;
if (array[random] == 0) length = random;
else array[random]--;
}
writeArray(array, length);
}
}

int main()
{
int length = 20;
int* array = new int[length];
getInitialArray(array, length);
writeArray(array, length);

if (coinFlip())
{
cout << "Player goes first.";
while (length > 0)
{
userTurn(array, length);
computerTurn(array, length);
}
} 
else
{
cout << "Computer goes first.";
while (length > 0)
{
computerTurn(array, length);
userTurn(array, length);
}
}
delete[]array;
array = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your question to make clear what you have done and what you need help with. I suppose the bit you are asking about should go in `computerTurn`?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm shoud be in computerTurn

Comment: please use intendation, the code is hardly readable